# Signing a Windows Store application with a corporate certificate

Tags: windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1, code-signing

We are trying to sign a Windows 8.1 Store application with a corporate certificate obtained from Symantec. The certificate was originally ordered for Windows Phone 8 application signing, but the same certificate should work for Windows 8.1 apps also.

On a fresh Hello World -project, when we try to choose the certificate from the manifest designer in Visual Studio 2013, an error message is given: "The Manifest Designer could not import the certificate. The certificate you selected is not valid for signing because it is either expired or has another issue. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=241478."

The certificate is most certainly not expired. On the "another issue" angle, a common suggestion for a possible cause for this issue was a publisher name mismatch between the certificate and the application, but that has been ruled out. If we skip some signing checks by adding a EnableSigningChecks=false to the .csproj file, we can sign the app, but then another error is given by PowerShell when trying to install the application: "Error: The certificate can't have the following extended key usage: 2.16.840.1.113733.1.8.52.1." Only the Code Signing and Lifetime Signing EKUs are allowed."

We asked for help on this issue from Symantec and Microsoft, but they didn't know how to help with this issue.

Has anybody encountered a similar issue with signing their apps? Is there a solution to this problem?

This issue looks to be the same as in [Choosing a certificate for a Windows Store application via the package.appxmanifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22288410/choosing-a-certificate-for-a-windows-store-application-via-the-package-appxmanif), where the solution was to get a new certificate. Is the only thing we can do to just buy a new certificate?

Comment: Check the certificate uses and make sure that it's a signing certificate (which it sounds like it's not). It's likely an Exchange certificate (or at least has that ability). I think you may need to request another certificate specifically for signing. You can test this by using MakeCert and creating a certificate for signing and one with some of the 'extended key usages' that your current certificate has. I'd bet that they are the cause of the issue.

Comment: We are running into the same issue, can anyone help? We have verified that the certificate has the necessary attributes: KeyUsage = Digital Signature (80) and EKU contains Code Signing (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3) so I believe the cert meets all criteria. Mine also has the other extended key that powershell complained about for @Mikko